# Can't find the exact TD value inside a row of columns

Tags: jquery

I have two descriptions containing the text SUM, but one that is bold (**SUM** and one that is not (SUM)). I want to get the td:eq(5) that has a description containing SUM without the b-tag.

The HTML is dynamically generated so I cant put any ID's, classes and so.

This is my code (it gives me green background on both sum fields):

```
$('#someTable tr').each(function () {
    var tr = $('#someId').closest('tr');
    var tdSum = $(tr).find('td:contains("SUM")');

    $(tdSum).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5)').css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please post your HTML or a jsFiddle.

Comment: If it's always the 'first' or the 'last', or if it's always the 'fifth' row then you could use a counter to make only the 5th row go green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `tr` is already available as the current loop item. To select the `td` which contains the text `SUM` but does not contain the `b` tag, use selector below as indicated. Then apply the formatting:

```
$('#someTable tr').each(function () {            
    var tr = $(this);
    var tdSum = $(tr).find('td:contains("SUM"):not(:has(b))').css('background-color', 'green');         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do a `each()` it should be recommended to use `$(this)`.

```
$('#someTable tr').each(function () {            
        if($(this).find('td:contains("SUM")').length > 0){            
            $(this).find('td:eq(5)').css('background-color', 'green');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using .not() and has to filter out the td's with a b tag

```
.not(':has("b")')
```

or filter function to filter out the elements

```
$(tr).find('td:contains("SUM")').filter(function(){
     return $('b',this).length == 0;
});
```